# The number of invertible linear transformations.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider a cube $ C $ centered at origin in $R^3$ . The number of invertible linear transformations of $R^3$ which map $ C $ onto itself is

(a) $72$

(b) $48$

(c) $24$

(d) $12$

I'm totally stuck on this question, don't know how to think...
Please help.

Comment: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/what-is-the-rotation-group-of-a-cube.505545/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider a vertex of the cube together with the three edges emanating from it, let us call it a *star*. An element of $SO_3$ can map the chosen vertex in any vertex of the cube ($8$ ways) and apply a rotation ($3$ ways) to the rays of the star. Once we know where a star is mapped we also know where the other vertices are mapped, so there are exactly $24$ elements of $SO_3$ mapping the cube into itself. If we take into account also the isometries which do no preserve orientation, we get that there are $48$ elements of $O_3$ mapping the cube into itself.

By considering the action on the four diagonals of the cube and if orientation is preserved or not, we get that the group of symmetries of the cube is isomorphic to $S_4\rtimes C_2$.

Comment: It looks like I won a downvoter on a regular basis. Hi there, may I request some explanation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: (+1) Just to compensate the downvote. (Just kidding; I was going to upvote this answer anyway.)

Comment: and I won a repo- enemy on MSE, I think. @Jack D' Aurizio

Comment: @SULTAN: no enemy, just a script reversing serial upvotes/downvotes!